# Angular 2, using ngZone.runOutsideAngular with a requestAnimationFrame loop

Tags: angular, requestanimationframe

From what i have read online the Angular team recommends that you should always call `requestAnimationFrame()` outside of the Angular zone like this:

```
this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  requestAnimationFrame(timestamp => {
    let timerStart = timestamp || new Date().getTime();
    this.myAnimeMethod(timestamp);
  });
});
```

But what about the loop ...

```
this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  requestAnimationFrame(timestamp => {
    let timerStart = timestamp;
    this.myAnimeMethod(timestamp, timerStart);
  });
});

myAnimeMethod(timestamp, timerStart) {
  let time = timestamp || new Date().getTime();
  let runtime = time - timerStart;

  /// animation logic here

  if(runtime < 10000) {

    // ------- continue to animate for 10 seconds -- //

    requestAnimationFrame(timestamp => {
      this.myAnimeMethod(timestamp, timerStart);
    });
  }
}
```

Was it enough to call `this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular()` on the first request or should i be calling it again `this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular()` inside `myAnimeMethod()` like this?

```
this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  requestAnimationFrame(timestamp => {
    let timerStart = timestamp;
    this.myAnimeMethod(timestamp, timerStart);
  });
});

myAnimeMethod(timestamp, timerStart) {
  let time = timestamp || new Date().getTime();
  let runtime = time - timerStart;

  /// animation logic here

  if(runtime < 10000) {

    // ------- request to run outside of Angular again while continuing to animate for 10 seconds -- //

    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      requestAnimationFrame(timestamp => {
        this.myAnimeMethod(timestamp, timerStart);
      });
    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You don't need to continue to call `NgZone.runOutsideAngular` from a `requestAnimationFrame` handler that came from a call outside Angular.

Long answer: Once you're in the "root" zone (which is what you get when you call `NgZone.runOutsideAngular`), any `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks will also run from that zone unless you explicitly request a different zone, e.g. via `NgZone.run`.

To check this, try calling the static function `NgZone.isInAngularZone()` from your `requestAnimationFrame` handler.

Note that I tested this with Angular 4.4.4 and Zone.js 0.8.18.

Comment: and @DevMike is this still relevant? I cannot get `requestAnimationFrame` to run at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a ngzon-flags.ts where you put all your exceptions for change detection.

```
// All events inside the BLACK-LIST Array will not trigger updates anymore from angular
// requestAnimationFrame wont trigger change detection
(window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; 
// Same for scroll and mousemove or any other event youll add
(window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove'];
```

Import that file to your polyfills.ts:

```
import './ngzone-flags'
```